# jQuery : Post Doesn't work when I click first and last time

Tags: jquery, dom-events

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var zone; //ZONE TO PASS THROUGH HTTP POST
 var NEcount; //COUNTER HOW MUCH NOT-EDITBALE ZONES USER MUST CONFIGURE 
 NEcount = 5; //IF I NEED 20(ZONES = CELLS OF MAP) USER MUST CONFIGURE 25-20=5 NOT EDITABLE ZONE FOR EXAMPLE(I'LL TAKE THIS VALUE FROM HTML CONTENT AND CALCULATED WITH JSP/JAVA) 

    $('body div#presentation div#map a').click(function(){
        zone = $(this).attr('href');
        zone = zone.substr(5);//i generate html code with jsp/java function href is like ="#area1"
    });

    $('body div#presentation div#map a p').click
    (
        function()
        {
            if($(this).attr('class') === "white")
            {
                $.post("MSservlet", {postsend:"updateMap",attrib:"editable",elem:"0",cond:zone});//Servlet call a PreparedStatement Query that update editable field to 0 where zone field is equal to var zone
                    NEcount--;
                    $(this).attr('class','gray');
                    if(NEcount <= 0)
                    {
                        $('#NEobb').html("HTML BUTTON THAT LINK TO END CONFIGURATION PAGE");

                    }
                    else
                    $('#NEobb').text("count = "+NEcount);
                }
            else if($(this).attr('class') === "gray")
                {
                $.post("MSservlet", {postsend:"updateMap",attrib:"editable",elem:"1",cond:zone});
                    NEcount++;
                    $(this).attr('class','white');
                    if(NEconta <= 0)
                    {
                        $('#NEobb').html("HTML BUTTON IMHO"); //LINK TO END CONFIGURATION OF MAP                            
                    }
                    else
                    $('#NEobb').text("count = "+NEcount);
                }
        }
);

});
```

I have problem with those jQuery posts.

I have a interactive map (simple one) product from a comfiguration page.
Config page ask me how much area I need. With a form field, through this number that I pass to servlet, web app generate a new page with a map (represented with Matrix of a Bean) and is like this:

```
(Map areas is like <a href="#areaNUMBERGENERATED"><p class="color"></p></a>)
```

With jQuery p color change normally but first post doesn't work(first click)
because pass a null zone(I don't know why).

And for each click after second I have this situation (I'm italian and it's hard to explain):

- I clicked area1: first post send zone = null to servlet(DB refuse update), color turned to gray from white
- Reclicked area1: second post send zone = 1(update works on DB normally,color turned to white again)
- I clicked area1 again: third post works normally zone = 1 and set editable to 0 on DB
- I clicked area2: post send zone = 1 (pass previously zone (I'm sure))
- I clicked area3: post send zone = 2 (that is the problem)
- I clicked again area 3: post send zone = 2 and update normally like should be
- I clicked again area3: post send zone = 2 and update normally like should be.

How can I fix it? and please Let me know why doesn't work too.

Thanks in advice.

An Italian student.

UPDATE POST:

I have 2 click functions on the same object.

So when I click on a map area/zone, post can't take in time the var zone(maybe).

Or

It's performed post before of var zone set (sorry for my bad english)

I don't have yet a solution.

Suggestions?

Comment: OMG.
When i click on map zone, I have 2 event triggered together.
with .click() action/function.
So post can't take zone in time(var zone isn't set yet?)
When I edited my question post , I just figured out why this doesn't work.

Comment: If you figured it out, you should consider posting as an answer in an effort to help future visitors.

Comment: But i don't have yet a solution, waiting expert answers.
 Yes sure, I'll do.

Comment: I'm confused by your comments.  Your first comment says you figured it out, your reply to my comment says you haven't??

Comment: @JohnieKarr I think the OP means that they've figured out *why* it doesn't work but haven't figured out a fix for it yet.

Comment: @BSMP, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @JohnieKarr Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks anyway.

I just coded a working solution.

Explanation:
I deleted second.click() action block(that contains posts) because was perfomed before of the function that setting the var zone variable._

So I moved if/else if block on the first .click() action code.

In html i have N-Zones like this:

```
<!--grigio = gray and bianco = white(italian translation) -->
<div id="map">
<a href="#area1"><p class="grigio"></p></a>
<a href="#area2"><p class="grigio"></p></a>
<a href="#area3"><p class="grigio"></p></a>
<a href="#area4"><p class="grigio"></p></a>
<a href="#area5"><p class="grigio"></p></a>
<br>
<a href="#area6"><p class="grigio"></p></a>
<a href="#area7"><p class="grigio"></p></a>
<a href="#area8"><p class="grigio"></p></a>
<a href="#area9"><p class="grigio"></p></a>
<a href="#area10"><p class="grigio"></p></a>
<br>
<a href="#area11"><p class="grigio"></p></a>
<a href="#area12"><p class="grigio"></p></a>
<a href="#area13"><p class="grigio"></p></a>
<a href="#area14"><p class="bianco"></p></a>
<a href="#area15"><p class="bianco"></p></a>
<br>
<a href="#area16"><p class="bianco"></p></a>
<a href="#area17"><p class="bianco"></p></a>
<a href="#area18"><p class="bianco"></p></a>
<a href="#area19"><p class="bianco"></p></a>
<a href="#area20"><p class="bianco"></p></a>
<br>
<a href="#area21"><p class="bianco"></p></a>
<a href="#area22"><p class="bianco"></p></a>
<a href="#area23"><p class="bianco"></p></a>
<a href="#area24"><p class="bianco"></p></a>
<a href="#area25"><p class="bianco"></p></a>
<br>

</div>
```

FOR Select  inside of the clicked  object i used $(this).children('p').attr('class')

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var zone; //ZONA DA PASSARE ATTRAVERSO HTTP POST
     var NEcount; //NON EDITABILI OBBLIGATORI DA INSERIRE
     NEcount = 5; // INIZIALIZZARE CALCOLANDO LE NE DA INSERIRE SE 21 = 4;

  $('body div#presentation div#map a').click(function(){
                    zone = $(this).attr('href');
            zone = zone.substr(5);

            if($(this).children('p').attr('class') === "white")//I added children for select p of the clicked object
                    {
                    $.post("MSservlet", {postsend:"updateMap",attrib:"editabile",elem:"0",cond:zone});
                        NEcount--;
                        $(this).children('p').attr('class','gray');//I added .children('p') to select class attr and change color
                        if(NEcount <= 0)
                        {
                            $('#NEobb').html("HTML BOTTON THAT LINK TO THE END OF CONFIGURATION");

                        }
                        else
                        $('#NEobb').text("counter = "+NEcount);
                    }
                else if($(this).children('p').attr('class') === "gray")//Same read comments up
                    {
                    $.post("MSservlet", {postsend:"updateMap",attrib:"editabile",elem:"1",cond:zone});
                        NEcount++;
                        $(this).children('p').attr('class','white');
                        if(NEcount <= 0)
                        {
                            $('#NEobb').html("HTML BUTTON THAT LINK TO END OF CONFIGURATION JUST IN CASE COUNT IS EQUAL 0"); //bottone che reindirizza alla pagina di fine configurazione.

                        }
                        else
                        $('#NEobb').text("counter = "+NEcount);
                    }

        });

});
```

I hope this help someone.